# Python 2.7 extremelly persisting error

Tags: python, django, import, path

I have this module

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append("C:\pysec-master")

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "pysec-master.settings")

from pysec.models import *

"""get a file from the index. it may or may not be present on our hard disk. if it's not, it will be downloaded
the first time we try to access it, or you can call .download() explicitly"""
filing = Index.objects.filter(form='10-K',cik=1090872).order_by('-date')[0]

print filing.name

"""initialize XBRL parser and populate an attribute called fields with a dict of 50 common terms"""
x = latest.xbrl()

print x.fields['FiscalYear']

print x.fields

"""fetch arbitrary XBRL tags representing eiter an Instant or a Duration in time"""
print 'Tax rate', x.GetFactValue('us-gaap:EffectiveIncomeTaxRateContinuingOperations','Duration')

if x.loadYear(1): 
    """Most 10-Ks have two or three previous years contained in them for the major values. This call switches the contexts
    to the prior year (set it to 2 or 3 instead of 1 to go back further) and reloads the fundamental concepts.
    Any calls to GetFactValue will use that year's value from that point on."""

    print x.fields['FiscalYear']

    print x.fields

    print 'Tax rate', x.GetFactValue('us-gaap:EffectiveIncomeTaxRateContinuingOperations','Duration')
```

I am trying to run it for a week now and whenever i hit <kbd>F5</kbd> to run it i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\pysec-master\pysec\example.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pysec.models import *
  File "C:\pysec-master\pysec\models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.db.models.query import Q
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 17, in <module>
    from django.db.models.deletion import Collector
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\deletion.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.db.models import signals, sql
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.db.models.sql.subqueries import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\subqueries.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.db.models.sql.query import Query
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 22, in <module>
    from django.db.models.sql import aggregates as base_aggregates_module
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\aggregates.py", line 9, in <module>
    ordinal_aggregate_field = IntegerField()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 116, in __init__
    self.db_tablespace = db_tablespace or settings.DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 49, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 132, in __init__
    % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)
ImportError: Could not import settings 'pysec-master.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named pysec-master.settings
```

If you need any other module from the projects please tell me and i will edit my question and put it in. The original files from the project are [here](https://github.com/lukerosiak/pysec).

The project is named `pysec-master` and it is on this directory: `C:\pysec-master`

The project is structured like this

```
C:\pysec-master(file)
|__C:\pysec-master\local_settings.py
|__C:\pysec-master\manage.py
|__C:\pysec-master\settings.py
|__C:\Python27\pysec(file)
   |__C:\pysec-master\pysec\__init__.py
   |__C:\pysec-master\pysec\example.py
   |__C:\pysec-master\pysec\models.py
   |__C:\pysec-master\pysec\xbrl.py
   |__C:\pysec-master\pysec\xbrl_fundamentals.py
```

My environment variables are:

`Path` --> `C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\pysec-master`

`PYTHONPATH` --> `C:\pysec-master;C:\;`

When i type `sys.path` i get

```
['C:\\Python27\\Lib\\idlelib', 'C:\\pysec-master', 'C:\\pysec-master\\pysec', 

'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python27\\lib', 

'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python27', 

'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\pysec-master']
```

I have checked:

- The environmental variables to be in accord
- Set the `DJANGO_MODULE_SETTINGS`

So what is the problem and how can i fix it?

Comment: Your `C:\ ` entry seems to not propagate from `PYTHONPATH` to `sys.path`.

Comment: Don't you need to import the settings file first before you try to use it?

Comment: Do you mean i should have the `C:\` in both `PYTHONPATH` and `sys.path`?

Comment: @TankorSmash Wow do you mean i should put like `from pysec import settings` ??

Comment: @TankorSmash whenever i try to type in the GUI `from pysec import settings` it gives me an error saying: `cannot import name settings`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable is set to `pysec-master.settings`, which is wrong for two reasons:

- `pysec-master` isn't a valid python package name (`-` is not allowed).
- if it were a valid package name, it's not found as a package (even if you have `C:` on your `PYTHONPATH`) because it has no `__init__.py`

For your configuration, `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` should probably just be `settings`